# Did Hogwarts students have to do a year over after DH?

Tags: harry-potter

During Deadly Hallows events, students still went to Hogwarts. But, I can imagine, the entire curriculum could be replaced, even in terms of ethics, where students were learning DA instead of DADA.

As such, after the fall of Voldemort, was this year deemed as invalid from ethics/study curriculum perspective? Did the students have to do the year over?

I am asking this since I find it hard to believe Ministry and others would find this year as appropriate in terms of learning.

Comment: After the crap they'd been through, I think it'd be assinine to tell them to stay.  Then again, this is the Ministry...

Comment: "The entire curriculum" was not replaced. DADA and Muggle studies were the only ones really affected. IIRC. And DADA had been messed up for years.

Comment: Many students missed part of the school year — including the untainted courses — when they went into hiding.

Comment: @JohnP Agreed, but would parents accept it as a legit year, after V was defeated?

Comment: Are you asking about the students at Hogwarts that year, or the students who weren't (e.g. Harry, Ron, Hermione, all Muggle-borns)?

Comment: @ibid First group. While students who did not attend Hogwarts on Year 7 for various reasons, lots of the students did. but I would not call this year as the most ethical curriculum. So I was wondering in these students had to take a year over due to the learning condition of that year.

Comment: there might be a distinction between "had to" and "could", that is maybe, speculatively, those who were confident in what they learned could take tests and move on, those who were not (or were not there) could repeat.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I highly doubt students had to retake this year.

1. The majority of the classes are still taught by competent teachers. Teaching magic that is outside of the issues at hand: Potions, Transfiguration, Charms, Herbology, and Astronomy.
2. The major issues with teaching came from Defence Against the Dark Arts, and an elective, Muggle Studies. As we have seen from the last 6 years of the school, the DADA class has varied between worthless and great. Lockhart taught absolutely nothing for an entire year and students simply moved on and counted that class as a loss. Divination, Care of Magical creatures has also been shown to be poorly taught during multiple years with no issues for the students moving forward.
3. While dogma changed and punishments increased, Voldemort holds Hogwarts as almost sacred, and holds the teachers in high regard, despite, political ideological differences.

   > I do not want to kill you. I have great respect for the teachers of Hogwarts. I do not want to spill magical blood.

   He is not one to limit magical knowledge like the Ministry tried in Book 5. He would allow the teachers to teach their subjects correctly with caveats (Muggles are bad, yay purebloods).